# Есть только один инпут очистить и возвратить дефолтное значение

Tags: jquery, форма

Помогите, пожалуйста, немного переписать скрипт, который был написан для того, чтобы при фокусе в инпуте очищать значение value, а если новое значение не введено, то возвращать дефолтное

```
$('.feedback-form-1 input[type="text"]')
            .each(function(i, el){
                $(el).data('oldValue', $(el).val());
            })
            .focus(function(){
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('oldValue'))
                $(this).val('');
            })
            .blur(function(){
                if ($(this).val().length == 0)
                $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'))
            });
```

Скрипт написан чтобы обрабатывать форму, где есть несколько инпутов, не могу разобрать, как его переписать, чтобы очищать и возвращать дефолтное значение, если в форме есть только один инпут? http://jsfiddle.net/N2MZz/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a").attr("hideFocus", "true");

$('.form-field-1')

.focus(function () {
    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
})
.blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0)    
        $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue')) ;          
});
```

});

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, работает.